# NULL values not removed after using `TRY_CAST`

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, where-clause

I'm using this query to convert and pull some date values:

```
Select 

Format(TRY_CAST(CD.Import_Date as Date),'MM/dd/yyyy') As 'Import_Date'

From dbo.QE_CD CD
Where CD.Import_Date IS NOT NULL And DATALENGTH(CD.Import_Date) > 0
```

But even after omitting NULL values I still receive them in my return set:

[image: img1]

It's my understanding that failed conversions using `TRY_CAST` return NULL - then shouldn't my where clause omit them?

Comment: You'd have to put the exact same SQL in your where clause e.g. `TRY_CAST(CD.Import_Date as Date) is not null`

Comment: @DaleK Got it - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause checks the original value of `import_date`, not the converted value. It is still possible that the original value would be not `null` and not empty, and that the conversion would fail and return `null` (typically, if the string column contains a value that cannot be converted to a date).

You want to put the conversion expression in the `where` clause:

```
select format(try_cast(cd.import_date as date),'MM/dd/yyyy') as import_date
from dbo.qe_cd cd
where try_cast(cd.import_date as date)
```

Side note: single quotes should be used for literal strings only, not for identifiers (such as column aliases).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the column aliases - so if I remove the single quotes I can refer directly to the alias in my WHERE clause, correct? And avoid having to use TRY_CAST again? Or nevermind, I guess that doesn't work :(

Comment: @dwirony: no, you cannot refer to an alias defined in the `select` clause in the `where` clause. You need to repeat the expression (or use a subquery or CTE).